# JSON Schema - specify field is required based on value of another field

Tags: json, dependencies, schema, jsonschema

Wondering if this is possible with schema draft 03. I've gotten dependencies working elsewhere, I think there is possibly just some creative use of them required in order to use them for specifying the `required` property of some field.

My current best attempt (which doesn't work) should give you some idea of what I'm after. I want a value required by default, and optional when another field has a particular value.

```
{
    "description"   : "An address...",
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "postcode": {
            "type" : "string",
            // postcode should be required by default
            "required" : true,      
            // postcode shouldn't be required if the country is new zealand 
            "dependencies" : {
                "country" : {
                    "enum" : ["NZ", "NZL", "NEW ZEALAND"]
                },
                "postcode" : {
                    "required" : false      
                }
            }
        },
        "country": {
            "type" : "string",
            "enum" : [
                // various country codes and names...
            ],
            "default" : "AUS"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is definitely possible with version 3 of the draft.  Since you have a complete list of allowed countries, then you could do something like this:

```
{
    "type": [
        {
            "title": "New Zealand (no postcode)",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "country": {"enum": ["NZ", "NZL", "NEW ZEALAND"]}
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "Other countries (require postcode)",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "country": {"enum": [<all the other countries>]},
                "postcode": {"required": true}
            }
        }
    ],
    "properties": {
        "country": {
            "type" : "string",
            "default" : "AUS"
        },
        "postcode": {
            "type" : "string"
        }
    }
}
```

So you actually define two sub-types for your schema, one for countries that require a postcode, and one for countries that do not.

**EDIT** - the v4 equivalent is extremely similar.  Simply rename the top-level `"type"` array to `"oneOf"`.

Comment: It's worth noting that in version 4, putting schemas in the `type` keyword will be forbidden.  You would instead probably want to use `allOf` or `oneOf`.

Comment: What about in version 4 of the specification?

Comment: I'll add something to the answer to clarify v4 alternatives

Comment: I mean specifically, is there a better / different way to achive the above with v4? I have a 100 line json schema so far... I don't want to double it for just one conditional require

Comment: Oh, right, so you're looking to avoid duplication?  You could try something like [json-schema-compatibility](https://www.npmjs.org/package/json-schema-compatibility), which normalises schemas to v4 syntax.  You can use it to convert v3->v4, or use it on-the-fly to use v3 schemas with v4 tools.

Comment: However, no, there is no syntax for this that works for both v3 and v4.  It is highly recommended to stop using v3, and move over to v4 completely - any tool that is still stuck on v3 probably isn't the most actively maintained.

Comment: The only trouble is, I'm using perl, where there is only ONE library which does json-schema... which the author said he has no intension of updating till the spec is "released", and I've just volenteered to update it to v4 (although I need to get this code working with v3 before I can commit any time to do that).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62527/discussion-between-relequestual-and-cloudfeet).

Comment: @Relequestual if you are still looking for an answer, check mines ;)

Answer (score 18):

If anybody is looking for a solution for draft 4 you can use `dependencies` keyword together with a `enum` keyword:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "play": {
            "type": "boolean"
        },
        "play-options": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "play-options": {
            "properties": {
                "play": {
                     "enum": [true]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this way`play-options` will always require `play` value to be `true`.

Comment: Yeah, it works. Thanks. It would be helpful if you tell way to invalidate ```{
  "play": true
} ```. That is, play-options is required if condition satisfies.

Comment: @Nilesh sorry, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The dependency in the answer means when `play-options` exists, `play` must be `true`. But when `play` is `true`, `play-options` don't have to exists.

Answer (score 8):

In the latest schema you can use the `oneOf` conditional to do this.

```
{
    "description"   : "An address...",
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "postcode": {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "country": {
            "type" : "string",
            "enum" : [
                // various country codes and names...
            ],
            "default" : "AUS"
        }
    },
    "oneOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "country": { "enum" : ["NZ", "NZL", "NEW ZEALAND"] }
          }
        },
        { "required": ["postcode"] } 
      ]
}
```

The `oneOf` condition requires that one of the conditions in the array is true.

Comment: Updated location of `oneOf`. Good catch! I think the mention of `oneOf` in the accepted answer is a little bit buried (I didn't see it when I was searching for an answer to this question), so figured I would make it more obvious.

Comment: thanks Mike . I've a similiar requirement, but my "Country" field needs to be free text, and require postcode only if country="NZ". Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

I just looked over the 03 version of the spec and I don't think what you are describing is possible. It's definitely not "Simple Dependency" and the description of "Schema Dependency" doesn't mention any way to consider the *value* of the property.

It sounds like what you need is "Conditional Schema Dependency".

There's some discussion of what's possible with Simple and Schema dependencies here:
http://groups.google.com/group/json-schema/msg/8145690ebb93963b

You might ask that group if there are plans to support conditional dependencies.

Comment: brilliant, thanks for the link. It seems like JSON Schema is pretty much in its infancy at the moment, finding any kind of documentation is hard! >< I think what is really required is a way for dependencies to manipulate the original properties of the schema they are defined within - this would allow overriding default values & requirements via dependencies as well as numerous other possible tricks.

Comment: The link provided in the answer contains a very valuable and practicale example! It's a shame there isn't better documentation / more practical examples for each part of the spec.