# JSON Schema conditional: field is required based on value of another field

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm trying to implement this condition: field is required based on value of another field i.e. if request with "index":"true" exists then "id" element required: true.

Here is a sample schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "test title",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "data": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Item"
      },
      "minItems": 0
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "data"
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "Item": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": [
            "integer",
            "string"
          ]
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How it can be implemented?

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use dependencies in JSON schema (draft-04)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375506/how-to-use-dependencies-in-json-schema-draft-04)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON Schema - specify field is required based on value of another field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029524/json-schema-specify-field-is-required-based-on-value-of-another-field)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your sample chema is strange for me, but for validation case in ticket description your can use this part of json shema:

```
"properties": {
    "data": {
        "oneOf": [
            {
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                    "index"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "index": {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "enum": [false]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                    "index",
                    "id"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "index": {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "enum": [true]
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This trick helps for you, if you want validate one parameter, when other parameters equals to some value.

Comment: This worked for me. The use case came up today because we validate data where right now, we have an optional field called `loginId` where our users are supposed to set the field if their users are logged in and omit the field if their users aren't logged in. They sometimes misunderstand and set the field to "anonymous" if their user isn't logged in, etc. It sounds like we're running into the consequence of using "null" to represent business logic. Using `isLoggedIn` and having `loginId` be required only when `isLoggedIn` is `true` (and ignored when `isLoggedIn` is `false`) solves this for us.

Comment: Unfortunately, the error messages generated (at least by the Go library I'm using right now) aren't very pleasant. When the document being validated has `isLoggedIn` set to `true` but omits `loginId`, the errors are: `(root): Must validate one and only one schema (oneOf)`, `isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn must be one of the following: false`. What we need the error message to tell them is that if `isLoggedIn` is set to `true`, they must also set `loginId`.

Comment: I'll explore custom error messages for this, and if I still can't make it work, do a second layer of validation after the JSON Schema validation to look for niche business logic stuff like this, with friendly error messages. Another alternative I'm thinking of is to use two schemas, one for the "not logged in" use case and another for the "logged in" use case, and ask our users to call one endpoint or another depending on whether their users are logged in, instead of trying to represent that within one schema. Then, the error messages will make sense.