# json schema field required based on value of nested field

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have tried [JSON Schema - specify field is required based on value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029524/json-schema-specify-field-is-required-based-on-value-of-another-field) but it does not work for me for the following situation.

**instance 1**

```
{

   "part1": {
      "subPartA" : {
          "value": "X"
       }   
    },
    "partX": {
         "propXX": "val1",
         "prop2": null

     }
}
```

**instance 2**

```
{

   "part1": {
      "subPartA" : {
          "value": "Y"
       }   
    },
    "partY": {
         "propYY": "val123",
         "prop2": null

     }
}
```

How does one make 
`partX.propXX` required if `part1.subPart1.value = "X"` 
AND
`partY.propYY` required if `part1.subPart1.value = "Y"`

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you mean that you want the value in data to be part of required property name (which is not possible using JSON-schema keywords), you can do this correlation:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["part1"],
  "properties": {
    "part1": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["subPartA"],
      "properties": {
        "subPartA": {
          "type": "object",
          "required": ["value"],
          "properties": {
            "value": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "required": ["partX"],
      "properties": {
        "part1": {
          "properties": {
            "subPartA": {
              "properties": {
                "value": {
                  "enum": ["X"]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "partX": {
          "type": "object",
          "required": ["propXX"],
          "properties": {
            "propXX": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "required": ["partY"],
      "properties": {
        "part1": {
          "properties": {
            "subPartA": {
              "properties": {
                "value": {
                  "enum": ["Y"]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "partY": {
          "type": "object",
          "required": ["propYY"],
          "properties": {
            "propYY": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does not work - try - http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/. I updated my question to insert commas to make the JSON instances valid.

Comment: was confused with your property names: part/prop... Corrected.

Comment: http://jsonschemalint.com/#/version/draft-05/markup/json?gist=a648a6e220dbe6488b4278279de17597

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this with "additionalProperties": false?

Comment: - propertyNames