# Require value depending on a property value

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

I have to build a Json schema to format each mesage an application need to send to another.

I already build this :

```
{
    'description': 'BLABLA',
    'definitions': {
        'M2M_message_input' : {
            'type' : 'object',
            'properties' : {
                'command' : {
                    'type': 'string',
                     'enum' : ['read', 'write', 'list', 'reset priority']
                },
                'path' : {
                    'type' : 'string',
                    'pattern' : '^\/'
                },
                'value' : {'type' : 'string'},
                'priority' : {
                    'type' : 'integer', 
                    'maximum' : 255, 
                    'exclusiveMaximum' : false,
                    'minimum' : 0,
                    'exclusiveMinimum' : false
                }
            },
            'required': ['command'],
            'dependencies' : {
                'value' : ['priority']
            },
            "additionalProperties" : false
        }
    }, 
    'type': 'object',
    '$ref' : '#/definitions/M2M_message_input'  
}
```

For now, i want to require some properties depending on the command value, like :

- if the command is setted to "read", i want to require the path,
- if the command is setted to "write", i want to require path, value and priority

etc...

I saw some topics about this, like [JSON Schema - specify field is required based on value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029524/json-schema-specify-field-is-required-based-on-value-of-another-field), but i wasn't able to adapt at my case, by usinf the draft v4.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way out :

```
{
    'description': '[...]',
    'definitions': {
        'readParameter' : {
            'type' : 'object',
             'required' : ['command','path'],
             'properties' : {
                'command' : {
                    'type' : 'string',
                    'enum' : ['read']
                },
                'path' : {
                    'type' : "string"
                }
             },
             "additionalProperties" : false
        },
        'writeParameter' : {
            'type' : 'object',
             'required' : ['command','path', 'value', 'priority'],
             'properties' : {
                'command' : {
                    'type' : 'string',
                    'enum' : ['write']
                },
                'path' : {
                    'type' : "string"
                },
                'value' : {
                    'type' : "string"
                },
                'priority' : {
                    'type' : 'integer', 
                    'maximum' : 255, 
                    'exclusiveMaximum' : false,
                    'minimum' : 0,
                    'exclusiveMinimum' : false
                }  
             },
             "additionalProperties" : false
        },

        'listParameter' : {
            'type' : 'object',
             'required' : ['command'],
             'properties' : {
                'command' : {
                    'type' : 'string',
                    'enum' : ['list']
                }
             },
             "additionalProperties" : false
        },


        'M2M_message_input' : {
            'type' : 'object',
            'oneOf': [
                    { "$ref": "#/definitions/readParameter" },
                    { "$ref": "#/definitions/writeParameter" },
                    { "$ref": "#/definitions/listParameter" }
            ],
        }
    }, 
    'type': 'object',
    '$ref' : '#/definitions/M2M_message_input'  
}
```