# JSON Schema Dependencies remove key if another key present without using oneOf as it is not supported by alpacajs

Tags: json, jsonschema, alpacajs

I am using a alpacajs library to construct my json schema into a form that doesnt support oneOf keyword.

I have a simple requirement where if one field is present then the other one should be hidden.

Is there a way to implement using json schema itself without using oneOf keyword.

Right now i am using `dependencies` keyword to handle my conditions.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "Company Setup",
    "description": "Company Wizard Setup",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Company Name"
        },
        "alternate_names": {
            "type": "array",
            "title": "Alternate Name",
            "items": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "maxItems": 5
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "name": "alternate_names"
    }
}
{
    "options": {
        "fields": {
            "name": {
                "dependencies": {
                    "alternate_names": "Value for empty Array?"
                }
            },
            "alternate_names": {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a stripped down version of my schema for the sake of clarity and i would appreciate if anyone can help me tell if dependencies can be used to remove a field too. I could potentially just use javascript to get this but i wanted to handle this just using schema as i am going to use same for validation too, infact schema has more use as a validator than form itself.

Since none of the field is boolean, i can't just put true and false in value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible to condition off the value of another property (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029524/json-schema-specify-field-is-required-based-on-value-of-another-field) so you might be able to introduce an additional property to toggle.

Comment: @MatthewCampbell Yes. I have tried that where i can, but in this case alternate names is an array that can have multiple values. So in case altername is not present in schema(In this case i am unable to assign a val to this field in property), name should be displayed. But otherwise if alternate has a value, then name should be hidden. Will update my question.

Comment: What about http://www.tothenew.com/blog/using-dependencies-in-json-schema-version-draft-v4/ when alternate is empty then name is valid?

Comment: That might work. Thanks for promptly pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: @MatthewCampbell It didn't work. I guess the issue was with alpacajs as i tried to use the same example and alpaca is not picking it up. Here is the small [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L8pnv366/3/) for the same.