# Pydantic generate json-schema enforcing field requirements

Tags: python, json, validation, jsonschema, pydantic

I have the following model, where the field `b` is a list whose length is additionally enforced based on the value of field `a`.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from enum import Enum

class A(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: list[int]

    @validator("b")
    def check_b_length(cls, v, values):
        assert len(v) == values["a"]


a = A(a=1, b=[1])

A.schema_json()
```

Generating the following JSON-schema:

```json
{
    "title": "A",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "a": {
            "title": "A",
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "b": {
            "title": "B",
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "a",
        "b"
    ]
}
```

Is there any way to enfore the additional validation being done by pydantic in the `check_b_length` function in JSON-schema? I.e. this could be done possibly via `oneOf`, as in this question: [JSON Schema - specify field is required based on value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029524/json-schema-specify-field-is-required-based-on-value-of-another-field) ... So its possible to enfore in JSON-schema, and possible to enforce in pydantic, but how can you map them?

Comment: No. How do you expect custom validators that _you write yourself_ to be auto-magically incorporated into the JSON Schema? You have to write your own schema additions as explained [here](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/schema/). Moreover, I don't think the JSON schema can reflect what you are asking here. You have not presented evidence that it is possible. Lastly, I struggle to see the purpose of this data duplication. If `a` must always be the length of `b`, then `a` should probably not even be part of the model.

Comment: I dont expect any custom validator to be compatible, just this particular situation that to my eye seems to be both possible in json-schema and pydantic. Regarding the problem itself, the presented class is a simplification of my problem, in which, i think, it makes sense to have this constraint.